# How to convert R dash app to and executable file?

Tags: r, deployment, plotly-dash, executable

I am new to Dash. I have created a R Dash app which runs locally. I need to let others use it . The problem is that I dont want to let others see my code. So, I want to convert my R Dash app into executable file, give them the .exe file and they can start using my Dash app on their computer. Any thoughts?

Thanks

I have come across this link https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-convert-your-dash-app-into-an-executable-gui-b1d4271a8fa7 which describes the process of converting python dash app to executable file but I couldnt find anything for converting R dash app to executable file. Can you let me know the process?